# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Folders' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a folder to the folders table in my SQL database using Entity Framework. I keep getting the error mentioned in the title when attempting the insert.

As the folder is new, the id is set to 0 when the folder is added to the context:

```
 public void CreateFolder(Folder folder)
 {
     context.Folders.Add(folder);
     context.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I assume that EF is trying to add the new folder with 0 as it's Id. I just want EF to leave the assigning of the Id to SQL. According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic), this should just work.

This is the relevant part of the migration file from when the table was initially added:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Folders",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    ParentFolderId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Folders", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Folders_Folders_ParentFolderId",
                        column: x => x.ParentFolderId,
                        principalTable: "Folders",
                        principalColumn: "Id");
                });
```

This is the Folder model class:

```
using FileSharingApp.API.Models.Folders;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace FileSharingApp.API.Models.Files
{
    public class Folder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public AppUser FolderOwner { get; set; } = null!;

        public ICollection<UserFolder>? Users { get; set; } 

        public IEnumerable<BaseFile>? Files { get; set; }

        public Folder? ParentFolder { get; set; }    

        public IEnumerable<Folder>? SubFolders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my data context class:

```
using FileSharingApp.API.Models;
using FileSharingApp.API.Models.Enums;
using FileSharingApp.API.Models.Files;
using FileSharingApp.API.Models.Folders;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FileSharingApp.API.Data
{
    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<
      AppUser,
      AppRole,
      int,
      IdentityUserClaim<int>,
      AppUserRole,
      IdentityUserLogin<int>,
      IdentityRoleClaim<int>,
      IdentityUserToken<int>>
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<BaseFile> Files { get; set; }
        public DbSet<XmlFile> XmlFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PdfFile> PdfFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ImageFile> ImageFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<AppUser>()
                 .HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
                 .WithOne(u => u.User)
                 .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                 .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<AppRole>()
                .HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
                .WithOne(u => u.Role)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<UserFolder>()
                .HasKey(key => new { key.FolderId, key.FolderOwnerId });

            builder.Entity<UserFolder>()
                .HasOne(uf => uf.FolderOwner)
                .WithMany(u => u.Folders)
                .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.FolderOwnerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<UserFolder>()
               .HasOne(uf => uf.Folder)
               .WithMany(f => f.Users)
               .HasForeignKey(uf => uf.FolderId)
               .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<Folder>()
                .Property(f => f.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't aware of this. I've now deleted the images and replaced with code

Comment: The column is defined as an `IDENTITY` column in your database table - what does your EF model class look like, and how is that field in the EF / C# class defined / configured?